# ExtJS file upload ajax response strips HTML from inside string inside JSON

Tags: ajax, iframe, extjs4

I have a form with a fileupload control in it, and I call form.submit with a success function.

My server side does the usual trick of setting the content type to text/html to get it to arrive in one piece.

In the success function, action.response.responseText does contain the JSON which I sent.

When it leaves the server, it looks like:

```
{
   html: "<div>a div</div>"
}
```

When it arrives in the success function, the tags are missing. What's going on? Do I need to put some sort of html cdata wrapper around the entire response on the server to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

A string in a string in JSON. As long as it is well-formed you are allowed to put HTML in string values (making sure you escape quotes etc.).

It's probably the function you're using to insert the HTML that's stripping the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the situation. When you ask ExtJS or JQuery to do Ajax for a form with a file upload, it has to use an iframe. For the response to come back correctly, it has to be of content type text/html whatever is in it. So it has to have it's HTML characters escaped for HTML, which I accomplished with a function from CommonsLang.